# How to make Emacs lock-buffer fail when it cannot lock a file?

Tags: emacs, elisp, file-locking

I want to some Emacs lisp to manipulate same file from different Emacs processes.  So I wrote the following script to check how `lock-buffer` works.  However, it stops when trying to lock the file by the second Emacs process (`find-and-lock-file $es2 /tmp/dummy`).  I need to go to another terminal and send `emacsclient --socket-name server-2 --eval '(kill-emacs)'` to stop the Emacs process. Emacs prompts what to do for the file if I open an UI by `emacsclient -t --socket-name server-2`, but I want to make it all done in the background and avoid using Emacs prompt to continue the process. How can I do this? Is it possible to make Emacs raise some error when it fails to lock a file?

**EDIT**: @event_jr proposed an answer using `file-locked-p`. I think it works most of the time. However, I think other Emacs process can lock the file between the execution of `file-locked-p` and `lock-buffer`. <strike>So, I will keep this question open.</strike> Solved. Thanks, @event_jr!

```
#!/bin/bash
es1="server-1"
es2="server-2"

start-server () {
    emacs -q --daemon --eval "(progn (setq server-name \"$1\") (server-start) (require 'cl))"
}

emacs-eval () {
    echo "@$1 >>> $2"
    emacsclient --socket-name "$1" --eval "$2"
}

kill-emacs () {
    emacs-eval "$1" '(kill-emacs)'
}

find-and-lock-file () {
    emacs-eval "$1" "(progn (find-file \"$2\") (set-buffer-modified-p t) (lock-buffer))"
}

start-server $es1
start-server $es2

find-and-lock-file $es1 /tmp/dummy
find-and-lock-file $es2 /tmp/dummy

kill-emacs $es1
kill-emacs $es2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to make `emacsclient --eval` return error code.  But You can make it print what you need to know:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

es1="server-1"
es2="server-2"

emacs=/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs
[ -e $emacs ] || emacs=emacs

start-server () {
  read -r -d '' script <<EOF
(progn
  (setq server-name "$1")
  (server-start)
  (require 'cl)

  (defun my-set-buffer-modified-p (flag)
    (flet ((ask-user-about-lock
              (&rest args)
;;              (signal 'file-locked args)
              (apply 'error "%s was locked by %s" args)))
      (set-buffer-modified-p flag))))
EOF

  $emacs -q --daemon --eval "$script"
}

emacs-eval () {
    echo "@$1 >>> $2"
  emacsclient --socket-name "$1" --eval "$2"
}

kill-emacs () {
  emacs-eval "$1" '(kill-emacs)'
}

find-and-lock-file () {
  read -r -d '' script <<EOF
(with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect "$2")
  (my-set-buffer-modified-p t))
EOF

  emacs-eval "$1" "$script"

}

start-server $es1
start-server $es2

find-and-lock-file $es1 /tmp/dummy
find-and-lock-file $es2 /tmp/dummy

kill-emacs $es1
kill-emacs $es2
```

EDIT: I've dug around the source a little bit and found a reference to
`ask-user-about-lock`, which solves it nicely.

Comment: Thank you! However, I am not convinced. Other Emacs process may lock the file between `(res (file-locked-p (buffer-file-name)))` and `(lock-buffer)`, right?  And it will stop the execution like the first  example.

Comment: You are correct.  I don't have a solution that covers all corner cases.  This question is getting old, maybe you should consider offering a bounty so it gets more attention from other people.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did find `ask-user-about-lock` but I could not make it work. I grepped through el files to find out how it is used but there was no caller. I guess it is called from C. Anyway, you get the bounty!

Comment: Yes, it was in C.  I've also filed bug #10989 because `signal` doesn't work from inside the eval block, it has to be `error`.

Comment: Is this the bug report? http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=10989 I don't understand because both emacsclient calls use `--eval "(error \"foo\")"` which does not hang, even if it is called multiple times. But `emacsclient --eval "(signal 'file-locked \"file is locked\")"` does hang. Probably this is what the bug report means to say.

Comment: Hi, I wrote another answer to check that `(signal 'file-locked ...)` works if it is not called from emacsclient --eval.

Comment: Thanks for checking the bug report.  I added to it with the correction you pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

I found another answer using `run-with-timer`, to bypass the emacsclient --eval bug, so that I can check that `(signal 'file-locked ...)` works in "normal" situation.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

es1="server-1"
es2="server-2"

emacs=/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs
[ -e $emacs ] || emacs=emacs

start-server () {
  read -r -d '' script <<EOF
(progn
  (setq server-name "$1")
  (server-start)
  (require 'cl)
  (defvar my-file-is-locked "undefined")

  (defun my-set-buffer-modified-p (flag)
    (flet ((ask-user-about-lock
              (&rest args)
              (setq my-file-is-locked "no")
              (signal 'file-locked args)))
      (set-buffer-modified-p flag)
      (setq my-file-is-locked "yes"))))
EOF

  $emacs -q --daemon --eval "$script"
}

emacs-eval () {
    echo "@$1 >>> $2"
  emacsclient --socket-name "$1" --eval "$2"
}

kill-emacs () {
  emacs-eval "$1" '(kill-emacs)'
}

find-and-lock-file () {
  read -r -d '' script <<EOF
(run-with-timer 0 nil (lambda ()
  (with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect "$2")
    (my-set-buffer-modified-p t))))
EOF

  emacs-eval "$1" "$script"
}

file-locked-p () {
  emacs-eval "$1" "(message \"my-file-is-locked = %s\" my-file-is-locked)"
}

start-server $es1
start-server $es2

find-and-lock-file $es1 /tmp/dummy
find-and-lock-file $es2 /tmp/dummy

file-locked-p $es1
file-locked-p $es2

kill-emacs $es1
kill-emacs $es2
```