# Run cron job using emacsclient but if no server currently open run with emacs --batch mode

Tags: bash, emacs, cron, org-mode, emacs24

Due to emacs interlocking files I want to run org-mobile command via cron but using the emacsclient:

```
emacsclient -nw --eval "(org-mobile-pull)" --eval "(org-mobile-push)"
```

but if there is no emacs server running I want the command to run using emacs batch mode:

```
emacs --batch --eval "(org-mobile-pull)" --eval "(org-mobile-push)"
```

I'm not sure how to accomplish this so curious if anyone has any ideas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm curious what you're ultimately trying to accomplish?  Why not just always
start a new Emacs process?  The additional overhead would be a small fraction of a second

On my 2 year old MBP:

> % time emacs --batch --eval nil
>   emacs --batch --eval nil  0.03s user 0.01s system 87% cpu 0.054 total

Going down your current path, you can check the exit code from `emacsclient`
to decide if you should run in batch

```
if emacsclient --eval nil >/dev/null 2>&1; then echo "run client"; else echo "run emacs"; fi
```

EDIT: I see you want to script an answer to the lock stealing question.  Check
out my answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608715/how-to-make-emacs-lock-buffer-fail-when-it-cannot-lock-a-file/9620663#9620663) for using `ask-user-about-lock` to solve this.

EDIT: So the idea is to redefine `ask-user-about-lock` to return t.  See docs:

> ask-user-about-lock is an autoloaded Lisp function in `userlock.el'.
>
> (ask-user-about-lock FILE OPPONENT)
>
> Ask user what to do when he wants to edit FILE but it is locked by OPPONENT.
>   This function has a choice of three things to do:
>     do (signal 'file-locked (list FILE OPPONENT))
>       to refrain from editing the file
>     return t (grab the lock on the file)
>     return nil (edit the file even though it is locked).
>   You can redefine this function to choose among those three alternatives
>   in any way you like.
>
> [back]

script example (remember to chmod)

```
#!/usr/bin/env emacs --script

(defun ask-user-about-lock (file opponent)
  t)

(org-mobile-pull)
(org-mobile-push)
```

Comment: Of course, if you're *really* out of luck one day, the server will terminate right between the `if` and the `then`... ;-)

Comment: @Thomas - The main issue is emacs locks the files so running emacs --batch gets the question of whether to steal, proceed, etc... and in batch mode this won't run if I have an emacs already open because the files are locked! If emacs is open, I would want to run the emacsclient. Also I was worried because I don't want the process sitting there waiting because it's waiting for s,q,p input. I thought cron set input to < /dev/null but this doesn't seem to stop the script when I run it from the terminal. Otherwise I might be fine with the script only running when emacs isn't open.

Comment: @event_jr - Then terminating in all other cases.

Comment: @JSpen see my edit for how to solve the lock stealing question.

Comment: @event_jr - I assume I would then just need to run the emacs batch script but how do I integrate the function my-set-buffer-modified-p. Sorry I was a little confused from reading the link on how exactly to force it to send an answer to the lock question while running in batch mode.

Comment: @event_jr - Got it working but ended up using emacs --batch and placing the defun in an eval statement. For some reason couldn't get the script to load my .emacs file. Was just loading the system file.

Answer (score 1):

The `emacsclient` returns an error code if the server is not running. If you are certain that the code you want to `eval` will make `emacsclient` exit normally, then the following should work:

```
emacsclient -nw --eval "(org-mobile-pull)" --eval "(org-mobile-push)" 2>/dev/null || emacs --batch --eval "(org-mobile-pull)" --eval "(org-mobile-push)"
```

Note however that this simple approach discards potential error messages you might be interested in (but only in the case where `emacsclient` is run).

Comment: Note that the code would always run twice if an error is encountered.

Comment: @event_jr: Exactly, hence this should only be used if you are certain that emacsclient will exit normally whenever the server is running.